# What is the best way to have different thm environments have different proof end markers?

Tags: environments, theorems

Is there a good way to make it so that the proof end marker (i.e., the `\qedsymbol`) looks one way for proofs of theorems, and a different way for proofs of lemmas?

I know I could locally change the definition of `\qedsymbol` anytime a lemma proof comes up, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this automatically, without manually redefining `\qedsymbol` each time.

**Edit (Further Clarification):**

Here's an alternate phrasing of my question: I have

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
```

in my header to make `theorem` and `lemma` environments. I want it to be the case that `\begin{proof} \end{proof}` environments after theorems have different endmarkers when compared to `\begin{proof} \end{proof}` environments after lemmas. Is there a way I could do this? For example, is there a way I can easily make some sort of separate `lemmaproof` environment which has a different endmarker than the default `proof` environment?

Comment: you have not shown how you define the environments but probably you can add `\def\qedsymbol{???}`  where you specify the font

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment (I might just not know enough about TeX). I've tried adding a clarification to my original question. Let me know if there's more relevant information I'm missing.

Comment: show a small complete document with a lemma and a theorem with the same qed and someone will show you how to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LaTeX3's hook management tools to tap into execution of code after the end of environments. For example,

```
\AddToHook{env/theorem/after}{<stuff>}
```

would execute `<stuff>` `after` the `theorem` `env`ironment. This way you can update `\qedsymbol` after every specific theorem-like environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

% Default \qedsymbol is \openbox
% Make any subsequent proof have unique \qedsymbol
\AddToHook{env/theorem/after}{\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\openbox}}
\AddToHook{env/lemma/after}{\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\clubsuit$}}

\begin{document}

% Theorem
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
This is a proof of the theorem.
\end{proof}

% Lemma
\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
This is a proof of the lemma.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
This is a different proof of the lemma.
\end{proof}

% Theorem
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
This is a proof of the theorem.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

---

If you're interested in a theorem-style specific environment, you can use something like this:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{lemmaproof}{ }{%
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\qedsymbol}{}{$\clubsuit$}% proof-specific \qedsymbol
  \proof
}{%
  \endproof
}
```

The above updates `\qedsymbol` locally, inside the newly-defined `lemmaproof`, while still allowing the use of the `proof` environment's optional argument.